# VS2012 Error C1107

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I am getting the following error:

```
fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'platform.winmd': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable
```

Steps to reproduce

0) Create a new empty project

1) C/C++ > General > Consume Windows Runtime Extension > YES

2) C/C++ > Code Generation > Enable Minimal Rebuild > No

3) Add a source file *.cpp, file can be blank

4) Attempt to compile

I tried to manually compare and change the project settings to match that in some sample code but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't understand what the problem you have, so

1. If you don't want to code against WinRT just set "Consume..." to false and the issue will be gone
2. If you want to code against WinRT you should perform an additional step: go to **General** and set **Windows Store App Support** to true

Comment: What flag is associated with that option? I have a Cmake that creates the vs project so how can I enable that?

Comment: @IonescuRobert, that's /ZW

Answer (score 5):

**To create a C++/CX Desktop application:**

In `C/C++ -> General` project properties, set `Consume Windows Runtime Extension` to Yes

In the same tab enter these to your `Additional #using Directories` enter the directories containing the `windows.winmd` and `platform.winmd` files. For me, with VS2017, that is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store\references;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\2.0.0.0;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\2.0.0.0

Then call [RoInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/roapi/nf-roapi-roinitialize) or use a WinRT main style function (to remove the warning C4447 about main threading):

```
using namespace Platform;

int main(Array<String^>^ args) ....
```

---

References:
[Using C++/CX in Desktop apps](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/29/using-ccx-in-desktop-apps/),
[Calling Windows 10 APIs from a desktop application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#4PeY5jWD7Mih3Wgz.97)

Comment: This seems to be the correct option if you want your app to keep targeting Windows.
Note: Had to append TargetPlatformVersion to UnionMetadata to find windows.winmd:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\$(TargetPlatformVersion)